# slow when copy files from external hard drive to external hard drive

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage, usb-3

I'm trying to transfer 1TB data from ext hdd A to ext hdd B thru a pc, both usb 3.0 interface connected to usb 3.0 port on the pc, but the transfer speed is like just 104MB/sec. Will the speed be faster if i transfer the data onto my pc first, then from pc to the other ext hdd?

Answer (score 2):

There could be many factors impacting the speed of the transfer.  Are the external drives *and* cables USB 3 compliant?  Do you have software, like a virus scanner, that could be reading the files and affecting the speed as they transfer?  Are there a lot of small files?  Small files often slow down file transfers in Windows.

In order to isolate the issue, you really need to dig down and troubleshoot.

However, it is possible that by the time you figure out the issue, you could have completed the transfer...  If it were me, I would just let the transfer complete, then do the troubleshooting.